# Unable to Access AWS Private Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have created an internal private api and want to access it from ec2 instance.
For this, I have create an endpoint and it has private dns enabled.
I have applied resource policy  that allows anyone to access (for now to test).

When I hit my api from ec2 instance, it gives below given error

```
The remote name could not be resolved:
```

Private dns enabled: true

Private dns name: *.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com

Resource Policy:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:REGION:ACC_ID:REST_API_ID/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "172.31.0.0/16",
                        "10.192.0.0/16"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

YES I deployed api after changing resource policy.

Security Group Of VPC Endpoint (Outbound Rule):

```
Type - All traffic
Protocol - All  
Port range - All    
Destination - 0.0.0.0/0 
Description - optional
```

**How do I access private api?**

I am using powershell Invoke-RestMethod. When I replace url with a public api then it works fine (No issue in script). Private api gives error only.

**Is the instance and the endpoint in same vpc?**

Yes, both screens show same vpc id.

**Note: I have 2 vpc and 2 endpoints created. One says default- yes and other says default-no.**

VPC that is connected to ec2 and endpoint is the one that has default-no and I am trying with that.

DNS Host Name and DNS Support?

[image]

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly is the API resource policy? What are security groups of the VPC endpoint? How do you try to access the api exactly? Did you deploy stage after any change made to api? Is the instance and the endpoint in same vpc?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my question with your requested details, please verify

Comment: "When I replace url with a public api then it works fine" - what do you mean? If you have Private DNS enabled for the endpoint, you just use the public endpoint. How do you exactly what to call private api differently? Do you have an example?

Comment: I have a public api in another account and I am able to access it from different account ec2 instance using powershell script.  The point to discuss this was that caller script is working fine. There is no issue with powershell script that consumes api

Comment: Did you associate VPCE-id with your API?

Comment: yes it is associated and still no success

Comment: Did you enable DNS hostname and DNS support for your VPC?

Comment: Yes, I have attached screenshot in my question (edited)

Comment: "Outbound Rule" - what about inbout rules?

Comment: Security group of vpc endpoint and ec2 instance are different and 443 port is not in inbound rules of ec2 as well as vpc endpoint.  Does inbound rule matter when I am calling api gateway private api from ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes they do, as vpce must allow incomming traffic from the EC2.

Comment: ok, I added https 443, destination 0.0.0.0/0 in inbound rules and there is a progress but no success yet.. I am getting forbidden now

Comment: " a progress but no success" - what does it mean? Can you be **specific** please.

Comment: Now calling private does not return 'The remote name could not be resolved:' but it returns ' {"message":"Forbidden"} '

Comment: If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for the current issue of with connection. ` {"message":"Forbidden"}` is rather a new issue, thus a new question could be asked. Acceptance of my answer would be apprecaited.

Comment: [Rahul Baisla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5416263) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67100067) saying "I have written following article to troubleshoot Private APIs [https://cloudnamaste.com/troubleshooting-api-gateway-private-api/](https://cloudnamaste.com/troubleshooting-api-gateway-private-api/)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **incorrect security groups** security groups on VPCE.

The solution was to **allow 443 incoming** connections `ingress` on VPCE for the API gateway.